# Using Season instead of Month for Time Display in Time Manager?

Tags: qgis, timemanager, gimp

Is there a way to make the season appear next to the year in Time Manager instead of the month? In the settings, I currently have DateTime selected with %Y-%m in the box. This makes the displayed time read 2017-10, for example.

I'm trying to make my frames into a GIF when I'm done and I'm hoping to not have to edit each individual frame in GIMP. Alternatively, if there's a way to edit the frames outside of QGIS in another program, I'm open to that, but I realize that a different stack exchange is dedicated to that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression like this to convert the month to a season name.

```
case 
 when month("datefield") in (12,01,02) then 'Winter' 
 when month("datefield") in (03,04,05) then 'Spring' 
 when month("datefield") in (06,07,08) then 'Summer' 
 when month("datefield") in (09,10,11) then 'Autumn'
end
```

Notes:

- Adjust months and season names to match your local seasons.
- Substitute the name of your date field where the expression says `"datefield"`.
- You can use this expression to create a new field with the Field Calculator, and then label the features with it. But I think there's a better way (see below).

---

The next step is figuring out how to display the "Season" value of the current feature on the image exported by the Time Manager plugin. Here's one method. QGIS has lots of graphic options, so there are probably other ways that I haven't thought of.

1. Substitute `animation_datetime()` for "datefield" into the above expression.

   ```
   case 
    when month(animation_datetime()) in (12,01,02) then 'Winter' 
    when month(animation_datetime()) in (03,04,05) then 'Spring' 
    when month(animation_datetime()) in (06,07,08) then 'Summer' 
    when month(animation_datetime()) in (09,10,11) then 'Autumn'
   end
   ```
2. Use that expression to put a label on the map at a fixed location. Make sure it doesn't conflict with the Time Manager date stamp. Fix the location using the data-defined label placement settings, as shown in the image below.

   [image]

If you want to display the season plus an additional value like the year (eg, Spring 2015), use `concat(string1,string2,string3)`, like this:

```
concat( [the expression from step 1], ' ', year(animation_datetime()) )
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, and I can set up the label to sit at a single point, thank you! Is there a way to include the year in the code so it comes after the season? Rather than having the season come from the label and the year from the TimeManager time display options?

Comment: Also, TimeManager might not have liked your test data if your month values were only one digit. I believe all the acceptable date formats for TimeManager are two digits (i.e. 01 for Jan). I changed your code to include 0s before the single digit months and that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad it works. I'll update my answer accordingly, and also add a formula for displaying the year in the label.